# Is there any meaningful difference between "import module; import module as blah" and "import module; blah=module"?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

This question is merely for my understanding of Python modules.

I am curious if there is any meaningful difference, other than readability, between these two lines:

`import module ; import module as blah`

and

`import module ; blah = module`

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identical and result in identical module objects:

```py
import pathlib as p1

import pathlib
p2 = pathlib

assert p1 is p2
assert p1 == p2
for attr in dir(p1):
    assert getattr(p1, attr) == getattr(p2, attr)
for attr in dir(p2):
    assert getattr(p1, attr) == getattr(p2, attr)
```

The above works in CPython 3.11 and PyPy 3.10 (v7.3.12).

In CPython specifically, the version with `as` uses fewer bytecode operations:

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  2 2023, 17:46:45) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.14.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: def g():
   ...:     import pathlib as p2
   ...:     return p2
   ...:

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     import pathlib
   ...:     p1 = pathlib
   ...:     return p1
   ...:

In [3]: dis(g)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (pathlib)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (p2)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (p2)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

In [4]: dis(f)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (pathlib)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (pathlib)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (pathlib)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (p1)

  4          14 LOAD_FAST                1 (p1)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

But this difference should not be noticeable in any real-world usage.

Note that you do not need to write `import module` before `import module as foo`. In every form of `import`, the module is loaded in its entirety and stored in memory under its original name.

Comment: It is stored in the module cache under its original name, but it is not made available to your program by that name unless you import it that way explicitly.  You are correct that `import module` is redundant though.

Answer (score 2):

The primary practical difference between these two approaches is readability and code style.

in usages wise

```
import package_a as a
```

will give `a` alias to `package_a`, and you can use the package_a with a name in your code

for case `import package_a` , you have to use it same as `package_a` in whole code

for case

```
import package_a
a = package_a
```

new object a is created with will behave same as `package_a`, but you can also use `package_a` in the code as well. which might lead to some confusion sometime.

The difference comes when we want to use the subpackages using `from ... import ...` statement

here is example

```
>>> import math
>>> import math as math1
>>> math2  = math
>>> math.sqrt(1)
1.0
>>> math1.sqrt(1)
1.0
>>> math2.sqrt(1)
1.0
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from math1 import sqrt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math1'
>>> from math2 import sqrt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math2'
```

when we try to import  (`from math1 import sqrt` or `from math2 import sqrt`)from `alias` ie `math1`or new assigned object ie `math2` in the example, we face module not found error.

so to use this way (alias/object annotation), we need to make sure use only the `.` to access subpackage/function/constant other wise if these package or object will be called anywhere else then avoid such usage

Comment: But both of the examples in the question provided the same module with the same two names, so your reasoning here doesn't apply.  Even if it's good.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, for these cases they provide same result. but when we want to access subpackages/module/function from them  they throw module not found error.

Comment: Your submodule problem is easy to understand though.  The importer simply doesn't know about aliases at all, no matter how they're defined.  But your specific example is easy to get around, just don't use the importer: `sqrt = math1.sqrt` or `sqrt = math2.sqrt`.